# Swift Custom UITableCell does work with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a TableView with a custom cell layout.

I add the Contraints to a label to be centered in the cell and it works. However when I change the device size, the Label is not centered.

I am very new with Swift, and I need some help Please!

Comment: Can you add an image with the constraints please?

Comment: We can get basic and great ideas from here https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started , https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/62-beginning-auto-layout/lessons/1

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is static constants , you need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-drag from the label to the contentView , and select **centerVertically** && **centerHorizontally** while <kbd>shift</kbd> key is pressed, but keep in mind this will work with static cell height , for automatic you should give the label  top , leading , trailing and bottom constraints to the contentView

Also don't forget to set textAlignment to center